# X labels matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, timeserieschart

I want to change x axis to years. The years are saves in the variable years.

I want to make plot of my data that looks like this:
[It should look like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8PW0.png)

However, I am not able to create x axes with a years. My plot looks like the following image: 
[This is an example of produced image by my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJBRF.png)

My code looks as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv("data1.csv")
demand = data["demand"]
years = data["year"]
plt.plot( demand, color='black')
plt.xlabel("Year")
plt.ylabel("Demand (GW)")
plt.show()
```

I am thankful for any advice.

Comment: `plt.plot(years,demand,color='black')` Assuming years are 2002, 2003 etc

Comment: Hello @JensMunk. Thank you for your advice, but it does not work. It produces result like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2Wfk.png

Comment: Hmm. The plot you show seems like it simply contains less points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `plot` method in your example does not know the scaling of your data. So, for simplicity it treats the values of `demand` as being one unit apart from each other. If you want your x-axis to represent years, you have to tell `matplotlib` how many values of `demand` it should treat as "one year". If your data is a monthly demand, it is obviously 12 values per year. And here we go:

```
# setup a figure
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2)

# generate some random data
data = np.random.rand(100)

# plot undesired way
ax1.plot(data)

# change the tick positions and labels ...
ax2.plot(data)

# ... to one label every 12th value
xticks = np.arange(0,100,12)

# ... start counting in the year 2000
xlabels = range(2000, 2000+len(xticks))

ax2.set_xticks(xticks)
ax2.set_xticklabels(xlabels)

plt.show()
```